# ¿Como puedo agregar datos a un csv desde selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, selenium-webdriver

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que abra el `script`, tome los datos de un párrafo y los agregue en una nueva linea. 
He podido hacer que los tome y los ponga en el archivo pero no lo hace en una nueva linea cada vez que se ejecuta el mismo.

¿como podría hacer?

Les dejo mi código para que vean

```py
import pytest
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.djangoproject.com/")
ContenidoExtraido = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, '//*[@id="homepage"]/div[2]/div/p[1]').text
print(ContenidoExtraido)

archivo="test.csv"
csv = open(archivo, "w")
csv.write(ContenidoExtraido)
csv.close()
time.sleep(1)
driver.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que abrir el archivo en modo `append` y agregar un carácter de salto de linea al final de la cadena a escribir. Te coloco las lineas que debes modificar

```py
csv = open(archivo, "a")
csv.write(ContenidoExtraido + "\n")
```

El modo `append` es para anexar contenido en el archivo, se coloca con la opción `"a"` que le indica a `python` que si no existe el archivo lo cree y si existe anexe información al contenido que ya posee el archivo.

El modo `write` como tu lo tienes es para escribir contenido en el archivo, se coloca con la opción `"w"` que le indica a `python` que si no existe el archivo lo cree y si existe trunque la información que posee el archivo y escriba la nueva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en python y todavia no conosco mucho. Lo de la segunda linea lo tenia en cuenta pero no lo de append. ¡Te agradezco, saludos!